# Current Waveform Graph

Tags: capacitor

My question is as such.

[image]

I honestly have no clue as to what im doing. Im not really asking for anyone to do the problem out, i would instead prefer if someone could point to a resource where i could learn how to solve the problem. THank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the relationship i(t) = C * dV(t)/dt, and basic knowledge of Calculus regarding graphical derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

By integrating the current over 1 second intervals, you can find the total charge transferred to/from the cap during that interval. You then use the relationship between charge, voltage and capacitance to determine the voltage at each step. in other words, the reference you need is your textbook.